# Is there a way to reorder vertices?

Tags: blender, topology

I tried to find a way to order vertices of my model from first image to look like second image but no success.
Is there a way to do that automatically ?[messy vertices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcJNu.jpg)

[ordered vertices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3df7.jpg)

I tried retopology and align but no success.
The file is here [messy file](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/9df9c36df635a42564827338a229c23f20240220101727/eac044?utm_campaign=TRN_TDL_05&utm_source=sendgrid&utm_medium=email&trk=TRN_TDL_05)

Comment: The answer is here
[enter link description here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/312271/is-there-a-way-to-reorder-vertices)